# How to `emit` event out of `setup` method in vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I know I can call the `emit` method from the `setup` method, but is there any way to emit event from any other functions without passing the `emit` method from setup method(not the the functions in the `methods` option, but a `useXXX` function) ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use `getCurrentInstance` from Vue. You can check it out in [the docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#getcurrentinstance).

Usage is like

```js
function useFunctionThatEmitsSomething(){
  const instance = getCurrentInstance();

  // do something
  instance.emit('event');
}
```

**Edit**: Even though this answer solves the author's problem, as per the linked docs, this method is intended only for **ADVANCED** use cases, *e.g* authoring a plugin or library. For common use cases, like building a simple SPA, using this is **TOTALLY DISCOURAGED** and should be avoided at all costs, since it can lead to unreadable and unmaintenable code. If you feel the need to use this in a case like that, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: From [the linked docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#getcurrentinstance): "Usage of `getCurrentInstance` is strongly discouraged in application code. Do **NOT** use it as an escape hatch to get the equivalent of `this` in Composition API."

Comment: I know that... But the author of the question asked SPECIFICALLY for this...

Comment: Yes, and I thought it would be helpful for future readers for them to see the warning message you omitted. If you'd like, I can edit it into the answer instead, but either way I think it would be more responsible to have the warning visible. Speaking for myself, I found this question via searching and didn't have the same constraints the asker did, so I was a bit surprised that your accepted/pinned answer recommended something that the docs so loudly discouraged.

Comment: Edited the answer. Now I think it's clear enough

Answer (score 64):

`setup` function takes two arguments, First one is `props`.
And the second one is `context` which exposes three component properties, `attrs`, `slots` and `emit`.

You can access emit from context like:

```js
export default {
    setup(props, context) {
        context.emit('event');
    },
};
```

or

```js
export default {
    setup(props, { emit }) {
        emit('event');
    },
};
```

[Source](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#context)

Comment: Right, or if you're using the `<script setup>` shortcut, [here's how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68261363/1352288).

Answer (score 33):

in vue3 typescript setup

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const emit = defineEmits()
emit('type', 'data')
<script>
```

- 20220626

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
const emit = defineEmits(['emit_a', 'emit_b'])
emit('emit_a')
emit('emit_b', 'emit_b_data')
<script>
```

Comment: Works perfectly also in Nuxt 3. Clean and simple.

Answer (score 12):

With Vue 3 setup syntax sugar

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineEmits } from 'vue'

const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'change', id: number): void
  (e: 'update', value: string): void
}>()

function yourFunction (id: number) {
  emit('change', id)
}
<script>
```

See docs: https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#typescript-only-features

Answer (score 11):

Here's the proper way to emit events programmatically (using javascript) in vue3:

```js
export default defineComponent({
  // See: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#declaring-emitted-events=
  emits: 'myEventName', // <--- don't forget to declare custom events emitted
  setup(_, { emit }) {

    emit('myEventName') // <--- emit custom event programmatically whenever we want

  },
})
```

The `emits` function can just as easily be passed as a param to any function not declared inside setup.

---

Side-note regarding other answers: we should avoid using `getCurrentInstance()`, which was intended for library authors needing access to internals of vue components (a.k.a. `this` of vue v2), when there are better alternatives. Especially when those alternatives were designed explicitly for our use case.

Comment: Why need to declare emits: 'specialClick'?

Comment: Hi @RomkaLTU `emits` are like `props` now in Vue 3: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/emits-option.html#_3-x-behavior

Answer (score 2):

```js
methods: {  
 minhaFuncao(){ 
    let data = "conteudo";
    this.$emit("nomeDoMEuEvento", data);
 }
}
```

SEE MORE AT :https://github.com/Carlos-Alexandre-Leutz/emitir-eventos-filho-pra-pai-com-dados-no-vue3

Answer (score -1):

```ts
export const useEmit = () => {
  const vm = getCurrentInstance()
  const emitFactory = (event: string) => (...args: any[]) => vm.emit(event, ...args)
  return {
    emit: vm.emit,
    emitModel: emitFactory('update:modelValue')
  }
}


const useButtonHandlers = () => {
  const { emit } = useEmit()
  const onClick = () => emit('click')
  return {
    onClick
  }
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?