# Vue Composition API: Defining emits

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

When [defining custom events](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#defining-custom-events) Vue encourages us to define emitted events on the component via the `emits` option:

```
app.component('custom-form', {
  emits: ['inFocus', 'submit']
})
```

Using Vue 3's composition API, when a standalone composition function emits custom events, is it possible to define these in the composition function?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you are using `script setup` you can use `defineEmits` which is a compiler macros and you don't have to import it:

> ```js
> <script setup>
> const emit = defineEmits(['inFocus', 'submit'])
>
> emit('inFocus')
> </script>
> ```

You can also use an object syntax, which allows performing events validation:

> ```js
> <script setup>
> const emit = defineEmits({
>   // No validation
>   inFocus: null,
>
>   // Validate submit event
>   submit: ({ email, password }) => {
>     if (email && password) return true
>     else return false
>   }
> })
>
> function submitForm(email, password) {
>   emit('submit', { email, password })
> }
> </script>
> ```

Note: the `submit` event will be emitted regardless of validation but if the validation doesn't pass, you will get a Vue warning:

> [Vue warn]: Invalid event arguments: event validation failed for event "submit".

[See it live](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-vuxyhy?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

---

Typing with TS:

> ```js
> <script setup lang="ts">
> const emit = defineEmits<{
>   (e: 'change', id: number): void
>   (e: 'update', value: string): void
> }>()
> </script>
> ```

The above code snippets are taken from [Vue.js Emitting and Listening to Events](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html)

Comment: If "the submit event will be emitted regardless of validation" what is the point?

"if the validation doesn't pass, you will get a Vue warning" What good is the Vue warning in the console log?

Comment: this is a copy/paste from the official Vue documentation

Answer (score 79):

No, because composition functions are used inside the `setup` hook which doesn't have access to the other options like `methods` and `emits`:

```js
export default defineComponent({
    name: "layout",
    emits: ['showsidebar'],
    setup(props, { emit }) {
        const showSidebar = ref(true);
        const { breakpoints } = useBreakpoint();
        watch(breakpoints, (val) => {
            showSidebar.value = !(val.is === "xs" || val.is === "sm");
            emit('showsidebar',showSidebar.value);
        });
        return {
            showSidebar,
        };
    },
    data() {
        // ...
    },
});
```

In the example, `useBreakpoint` offers only some logic that the component could use. If there was a way to define the `emits` option in the composition function, then the function would always emit the event, even if the function is only used inside the component that defines the handler of the emitted event.

with the new script setup syntax you could do it as follows:

```html
<script setup>
 import { defineEmits,watch,ref } from 'vue'
    
    const emit = defineEmits(['showsidebar'])
    const showSidebar = ref(true);
    const { breakpoints } = useBreakpoint();
    watch(breakpoints, (val) => {
            showSidebar.value = !(val.is === "xs" || val.is === "sm");
            emit('showsidebar',showSidebar.value);
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 71):

I did it like this with the script setup syntax:

```html
<script setup>
    import { defineEmits } from 'vue'

    const emit = defineEmits(['close'])

    const handleClose = () => {
        emit('close')
    }
</script>
```

Comment: As of today this doesn't work with Nuxt3(vue3) due to Vite.

`__vite_ssr_import_2__.defineEmit is not a function`

Comment: It work well, but you have a typo. It is not `defineEmit` but `defineEmits` as described here https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#using-custom-directives

Comment: And also not forget that `defineEmits` is a compiler macro and no longer needs to be imported.

Comment: How can we listen to the event inside the script when using ```<script setup>```?

Comment: As well, you can get away with no specific defined items (because, maybe your emits are dynamic?); `const emit = defineEmits()` seems to work fine for me.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to get all the `context`:

```js
    setup(props, context) {
       // console.log(context)
       context.emit("update:modelValue", data)
    },
```

Comment: This works fine with the Composition API for Vue2.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `{}` to access the context options.

```
setup(props, {emit} ) {
    emit("update:modelValue", data)
}
```