# I got this error " this.$emit is not a function " I'm using vue 3 and quasar framework

Tags: javascript, frontend, vuejs3, quasar-framework, eventemitter

```
function irAlLink(link) {
  if (linkAbierto.value.includes(link)) {
    this.$emit('linkClickeado', link)
    router.replace('/main')
  } else {
    this.$emit('linkClickeado', link)
    router.replace(link)
  }
}
```

I'm trying to giving the link to my other component:

```
<EssentialLink v-for="link in links2" :key="link.text" v-bind="link" @linkClickeado="agregarLink()" :linkAbierto="linkAbierto"/>
```

Comment: Hi, where is your code located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within vue3 it isn't possible to access `this.` within the setup script.

Please check this post:

[How to `emit` event out of `setup` method in vue3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65652584/how-to-emit-event-out-of-setup-method-in-vue3)